# IE10 ignores overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, reactjs, internet-explorer-10

I have a simple ReactJS Modal window like so:

```
const Modal = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="modal">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <h2>MODAL</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-content">
          ...bunch of long content...
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

styled with modal-behaviour like so:

```
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;

  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid blue;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.modal-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lime;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.modal-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This works fine in pretty much everything except IE10 (and probably below).

I have mucked around with variations of `overflow` on different parts of the component, but I can't for the life of me get IE10 to behave.

[JSBin here](http://jsbin.com/jizuhiqoko/1/edit?css,js,output)

Any advice on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: try giving .modal a height instead of top+bottom

Comment: but I don't know the size of the users window...

Comment: Replacing top/bottom with `height` doesn't change the situation anyway :(

Comment: since your using flexbox, you might need to use some prefixes, `-ms-flexbox` comes to mind.

Comment: thanks, I'm using autoprefixer and just threw together the demo - missed that :)  will update